# How to get snippet admin URL

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I'm trying to get the admin snippet URL for an object, for example, I have products listed as snippets and one of their URL's is:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/snippets/blog/blogproduct/edit/18/
```

I would like to programmatically get that, for example:

```
product = BlogProduct.objects.get(id=18)
print(product.admin_edit_url)

# expected result: http://localhost:8000/admin/snippets/blog/blogproduct/edit/18/
```

I could manually build this as per below but I prefer to get it programmatically

```
print(f"http://localhost:8000/admin/snippets/blog/blogproduct/edit/{product.id}/")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wagtail provides [an `AdminURLFinder` class](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/7504) for this purpose:

```
from wagtail.admin.admin_url_finder import AdminURLFinder
finder = AdminURLFinder()
product = BlogProduct.objects.get(id=18)
print(finder.get_edit_url(product))
```